# Spark reduce by some keys in reduceByKey

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

After loading a large file into an `RDD0`, I create (very time consuming) `RDD1` of pairs

```
((k1,k2), value)
```

and apply `reduceByKey`. For `RRD0` I need to create a `RDD2` of pairs

```
((k1,k3), value)
```

its creation equally time consuming, and apply another `reduceByKey`.

Can I create an `RDD12` of pairs

```
((k1,k2,k3), value)
```

and apply `reduceByKey` first on `(k1,k2)` and then on `(k1,k3)` so that I save time not creating `RDD1` and `RDD2`?

Answer (score 0):

Your first operation should be a [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) and return

```
[((k1,k2), value1), ((k1,k3)), value2)]
```

And then run the reduceByKey afterwards and you'll have your results

Comment: Thanks for your response. What type is the returned element, and how to reduceByKey on it, namely how to choose which key?